# Convert SQL query to PySpark dataframe for case when on joined dataframes

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       id,
       a.val1,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE
       END AS inf,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN coalesce(b.val2, a.val2)
           ELSE a.val2
       END mob,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN coalesce(b.val3, a.val3)
           ELSE a.val3
       END cli,
       a.val3 fam,
       count(*) unique_val
FROM c
JOIN a ON (c.e_id = a.e_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (c.m_id = b.m_id)
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         6,
         7
```

I am trying to convert this query to python spark version. I tried different ways but it's not working with joining on multiple dataframes.

My version of PySpark code which is ending up in errors:

```py
joined = c.join(a, c.e_id == a.e_id).join(b, c.m_id == b.m_id, "left_outer")

df = (
    joined.select(["dt", "id", "a.val1"])
    .withColumn("inf", when(F.col("b.val1") == False, True).otherwise(False))
    .withColumn(
        "mob",
        when(F.col("b.val1") == False, coalesce(b.val2, a.val2)).otherwise(a.val2),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "cli",
        when(F.col("b.val1") == False, coalesce(b.val3, a.val3)).otherwise(a.val3),
    )
    .withColumnRenamed("a.val3", "fam")
    .groupby(["dt", "id", "a.val1", "inf", "mob", "cli", "fam"])
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("count", "unique_val")
)
```

If anyone can help , will be so much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your PySpark code?

Comment: @LuizViola I just updated question with my pyspark code

Comment: @data_coder what are the errors ?

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without data, without the errors, it is almost impossible to understand what is wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. replace `df.column_name` with `df["column_name"]` as string within bracket is not case sensitive.
2. do you select as one statement, without the `withColumn` as in your sql query.
3. `b["val1"] == False` should be replaced with `~b["val1"]` (sql `not b.val1`)
4. if you do not explain what are the errors (as we cannot reproduce your current code without any related data), it is almost impossible to understand what could go wrong.

```py
df = (
    joined.groupBy(
        "dt",
        "id",
        a["val1"],
        when(~b["val1"], True).otherwise(False).alias("inf"),
        when(~b["val1"], coalesce(b["val2"], a["val2"])).otherwise(a["val2"]).alias("mob"),
        when(~b["val1"], coalesce(b["val3"], a["val3"])).otherwise(a["val3"]).alias("cli"),
        a["val3"].alias("fam"),
    )
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("count", "unique_val")
)
```

---

have you tried :

```py
df = spark.sql("""
SELECT dt,
       id,
       a.val1,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE
       END AS inf,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN coalesce(b.val2, a.val2)
           ELSE a.val2
       END mob,
       CASE
           WHEN b.val1 = FALSE THEN coalesce(b.val3, a.val3)
           ELSE a.val3
       END cli,
       a.val3 fam,
       count(*) unique_val
FROM c
JOIN a ON (c.e_id = a.e_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (c.m_id = b.m_id)
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         6,
         7
""")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! First one worked. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I made a mistake by keeping select and case when as different statements.

Comment: @data_coder you can replace the `select` keyword in first line with `groupBy` and delete the actual `groupby` line. I made the update.